# How can I update the value for a XML node using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can I change the value of the node 
`<Test>Test</Test>` to
`<Test>Power</Test>`?

**Example**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DeploymentDate" value="test" />
        <add key="DateOfInitialization" value="Vinoj" />
    </appSettings>
    <Test>Test</Test>
</configuration>
```

Here's the PowerShell script I currently use:

```cs
$configuration = "app.config"
[xml]$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($configuration)
$xml.selectnodes("/configuration/Test") = {"UST"}
$xml.Save($configuration)
```

Comment: There's a box above the question title saying "This question already has answers here..." but it links to a question that was posed in 2013.  This one was asked in 2010 and already had answers that year as you can see.  So... that box should be removed

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but the example should give you and idea:

```
$file = 'c:\temp\aa\ServerService.exe.config'
$x = [xml] (Get-Content $file)
Select-Xml -xml $x  -XPath //root/level |
    % { $_.Node.'#text' = 'test'
        $_.Node.SomeAttribute = 'value'
      }
$x.Save($file)
```

You don't need to use .NET for xpath queries. Just stay with PowerShell (with `Select-Xml`). 

It is also common to load xml file via `Get-Content` and cast it to `[xml]` which creates `XmlDocument` and loads the file content.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you please tell me what | % does in general?

Comment: It means `foreach-object`. You can find it with `Get-Alias -Name %`

Comment: you can also access the test value `$xml.configuration.test` - Pretty slick (given its not a collection) but then you can use `foreach ($thing in $xml.things) { $thing.value } ` . I am here cause I need to save my XML file after incrementing version. And this helped me. +1

Comment: also, you asked about the pipe `|`.  That gets the output from the previous command and feeds it into the next command, which in this case is a where-object loop using what was found from `Select-Xml -xml $x -XPath //root/level`.  So every object passes through, but the % helps filter what you're looking for.