# Escaping a colon in powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have the following piece of code in Powershell trying to read back a piece of XML.

```
$path = "C:\path\8429006775491.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)
$xml.ern:NewReleaseMessage
```

The problem is the colon. I've tried to escape it with `'` but it doesn't seem to work. Also tried to put it in `{}`

If I edit the colon in the XML file itself and change the code accordingly it reads back fine but unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: Can you include the relevant section of the xml file and it's structure?

Comment: you could use $xml.SelectSingleNode()

Comment: <ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/ern/341" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/ern/341 http://ddex.net/xml/ern/341/release-notification.xsd" MessageSchemaVersionId="ern/341">

Comment: It's not the first node i need to read but that is the bit i am stuck on.

Comment: Does $xml.'ern:NewReleaseMessage' work?

Comment: No, I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for .NET to understand the namespace prefixes, you'll need a Namespace Manager object:

```
$path = "C:\path\8429006775491.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)

$XmlNSManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable
$XmlNSManager.AddNamespace('ern','http://ddex.net/xml/ern/341')
$XmlNSManager.AddNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')

# Now you can use SelectNodes() with your namespace manager:

# If NewReleaseMessage is the root node
$xml.SelectNodes('/ern:NewReleaseMessage',$XmlNSManager)

# If NewReleaseMessage is a descendant of the root node
$xml.SelectNodes('//ern:NewReleaseMessage',$XmlNSManager)
```

Comment: That seems to work. Ok, so how do i go about editing the values in some of the nodes further down?
<Value>
    <ValueID>9849287429874982</ValueID>
</Value>
and i want to edit the value in  <ValueID>9849287429874982</ValueID>

Comment: @s4ndz This should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428559/powershell-script-to-update-xml-file-content