# What is the way to escape colon in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell in a script file:

```
cd "$env:systemdrive:\$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
```

Expanded, I want this to do something similar to this:

```
cd "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\f1wkii3l.default"
```

But when I run it, I get:

> cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '\C' does not exist.

I am guessing the colon I put in there to be at the end of `C:\` is causing problems.

I tried:

```
cd "${env:systemdrive}:\${env:APPDATA}\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
```

But then I get the error:

> cd : Cannot find a provider with the name 'C'.

**How can I escape the colon so that powershell just sees it as normal text?**

*NOTE: I looked at this question: [Escaping a colon in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724250/escaping-a-colon-in-powershell) and the answer is all about .NET and does not answer my question (though the question is very similar).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers are valid for troubleshooting and for your task at hand.  One suggestion I have, and what I consider a best-practice, is making use of `Join-Path` anytime you are dealing with paths so you don't have to worry about trailing or beginning path separators.

**This example**

```
$d1 = "${env:APPDATA}\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
$d2 = Join-Path ${env:APPDATA} "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
$d3 = Join-Path ${env:APPDATA} "Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
Write-Output "d1 = '$d1'"
Write-Output "d2 = '$d2'"
Write-Output "d3 = '$d3'"
```

**Produces**

```
d1 = 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default'
d2 = 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default'
d3 = 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default'
```

All are acceptable, and I would tend to use the `d3` version in my own scripts.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as Join-Path answers the secondary question of how to escape paths with Powershell (without using .Net methods)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape anything there. The `APPDATA` environment variable already includes the drive, so you only need

```
cd "${env:APPDATA}\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
```

`${env:systemdrive}:\${env:APPDATA}` would create a path `C:\C:\Users\...`, which is indeed invalid.

Answer (score 2):

If you `write-host` those environmental variables, you'll see that:

```
PS C:\>write-host $env:systemdrive
C:

PS C:\>write-host $env:appdata
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming
```

So your current attempt expands to `C:C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\...`
So all you need is the command:

```
cd "$env:Appdata\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
```