# Possible to transform ELMAH subject in VSTS release?

Tags: elmah, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We've setup our release pipeline using a single build that triggers a release to multiple environments with variables for XML config substitution.  This is working quite well for any config values in appSettings or connectionStrings but we have an issue with the subject of the ELMAH error emails.  Prior to switching to VSTS Releases we were using publish profiles and config transformation to make the config updates, now that we're in VSTS we've lost the ability to transform the ELMAH email subject, is anyone aware of a way to do this?

[image: web.config screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires just a few lines of Powershell to edit an Xml file, e.g. [Powershell script to update XML file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428559/powershell-script-to-update-xml-file-content).

Or you can use one of the many free extensions in the VSTS Marketplace, for example Guillaume's [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform).

Comment: I find it annoying that I have to use two different tasks to achieve the same goal.  Variable substitution only works for elements in the appSettings and connectionStrings sections, so we're forced to use Powershell or another task to replace nodes in any other section of a config file...  : (