# How to read .xls file and create .xml based on the value entered in the .xls?

Tags: powershell

I want to read value from `.xls` and write it as `.xml` based on the input provided in the `.xls`.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:yourfile*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_ | ForEach  { $_ -replace '[MYID]', 'MyValue' }) |
     Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428559/powershell-script-to-update-xml-file-content/16429111 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/grabbing-excel-xlsx-values-with-powershell/ can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sheetNumber = 1 
$startRow = 2
$endRow = 3
$searchResouceId = 3
$searchResourceName = 1
$xls = "C:\Codes\book1.xlsx"
$find = '<title></title>'

$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($xls)
$sh = $wb.Sheets.Item($sheetNumber)
$row = $startRow;
for ($j = 1; $j -le $endRow; $j++) {
    $resourceId = $sh.Cells.Item($row, $searchResouceId).Value2
    $resourceName = $sh.Cells.Item($row, $searchResourceName).Value2
    Write-Output "Creating : $resourceId"
    Copy-Item "sample.html" -Destination "C:\Codes\$resourceName.html"
    $file = "C:\Codes\$resourceName.html"
    $row = $row  + 1
    $replace = "<title>$resourceId/title>"
    (Get-Content $file).replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file
}

$excel.Workbooks.Close()
```