# How to update version in POM file on branch after build number is incremented in Azure Pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, pom.xml

I am new to both Azure Pipelines as well as Maven. I have this pipeline setup that changes the version number in the POM file and then executes a maven clean install:

```
Trigger:
- none

pool:
   name: Azure Build VM
   demands:
   - Cmd

name: $(BuildVersion)$(Rev:.r)

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'InternalRepo'

- script: |
    cd JavaRESTfulEngine
    mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  displayName: 'Change POM Version'

- script: |
    cd JavaRESTfulEngine
    mvn clean install
    rename C:\Users\Build\.m2\repository\net\windward\JavaRESTfulEngine\$(Build.BuildNumber)\JavaRESTfulEngine-$(Build.BuildNumber).war ROOT.war
    mkdir C:\Users\Build\.m2\repository\net\windward\JavaRESTfulEngine\$(Build.BuildNumber)\App_Data
    mkdir C:\Users\Build\.m2\repository\net\windward\JavaRESTfulEngine\$(Build.BuildNumber)\App_Data\requests
    rename C:\Users\Build\.m2\repository\net\windward\JavaRESTfulEngine\$(Build.BuildNumber)\JavaRESTfulEngine-$(Build.BuildNumber).war ROOT.war
    del C:\Users\Build\.m2\repository\net\windward\JavaRESTfulEngine\$(Build.BuildNumber)\_remote.repositories 
  displayName: 'Build with Maven'
```

This works, and the artifact has the right version number. My question is can I then proceed to update the version in the POM on the master branch to match $(Build.BuildNumber) such that the next time I pull from master I have the same version as the latest build? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the version in the POM to match $(Build.BuildNumber), you could try following steps.

My pom.xml is under the root directory, and I want to update the `modelVersion`.
[image]

```
# Specify the file path
$xmlFileName= "pom.xml"
# Read the existing file
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFileName
# If it was one specific element you can just do like so:
$xmlDoc.project.modelVersion = "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
#Remove the old pom.xml
Remove-Item $xmlFileName
# Then you can save that back to the xml file
$xmlDoc.Save("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\pom.xml")
# Print new file content
gc $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\pom.xml
```

See this thread: [Powershell script to update XML file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428559/powershell-script-to-update-xml-file-content) for more details.

Comment: thank you! I was able to use this as a template for a powershell script. I also had to commit/push the changed file to master at the end but it works!

Comment: Why should you edit the modelVersion? I think you want to change the version.
See: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html
Notice that modelVersion contains 4.0.0. That is currently the only supported POM version, and is always required.