# Editing XML with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

OK, I'm feeling like a really big idiot here. I've been working with Powershell for a little while more for administrative purposes at work. That said, scripting is not my strong suit.

Right now, I'm trying to write a PS script to add a section to an XML on a bunch of machines to add settings to workaround an issue we've been having with a certain application

The XML file looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <ProvidersConfiguration>
    <Providers>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
    </Providers>
  </ProvidersConfiguration>
  <FacadeSettings>
    <Providers>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
    </Providers>
  </FacadeSettings>
</configuration>
```

now, I've been googling and searching for hours and there's something i'm just not getting. because i can load the file in my script, navigate all the settings, even modify existing values, but that's not what I need to do.

I need to add a section like this

```
<NewSettings>
    <add Name="setting"/>
  </NewSettings>
```

so that my config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <ProvidersConfiguration>
    <Providers>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
    </Providers>
  </ProvidersConfiguration>
  <FacadeSettings>
    <Providers>
      <add Name="testdata"/>
    </Providers>
  </FacadeSettings>
   <NewSettings>
      <add Name="setting"/>
   </NewSettings>
</configuration>
```

it's the NewSettings section I can't figure out and I'm sure that when I wrap my head around it, I'll go "OH...", but right now I'm banging my head on the wall and could use some help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update the value for a XML node using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202567/how-can-i-update-the-value-for-a-xml-node-using-powershell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Create xml doc - assumes your xml is file E:\Scratch\test.xml
# If it's already in a variable, use $xml = [xml]$myVariable

$xml = [xml](Get-Content E:\Scratch\test.xml)

# Create new element for <NewSettings>
$newSettings = $xml.CreateElement("NewSettings")

# Create new element for <add>
$add = $xml.CreateElement("add")

# Create attribute "Name", and set its value
$settingsAttribute = $xml.CreateAttribute("Name")
$settingsAttribute.Value = "setting"

# Add attribute to <add>
$add.Attributes.Append($settingsAttribute)

# Add <add> to <NewSettings>
$newSettings.AppendChild($add)

# Add <NewSettings> to <configuration>
$xml.configuration.AppendChild($newSettings)

# Save to file
$xml.Save("E:\Scratch\new.xml")
```

Comment: ah....So I was trying to do it backwards I think. If I understand this, we're creating the XML table on it's own, and then appending it to the existing XML where I was trying to add to the existing from the start, trying to work my way up(down?) the tree.

Comment: OK, tried it out after some editing to make it more human readable for what I want and it's working. I was on the right path to begin with trying to create elements but wasn't quite grasping the part about appending them. I knew I was missing something and now it makes sense. Thanks a LOT Kevin