# How can I include a connectionstring for the build process, which isn't on Git?

Tags: appveyor

I've extracted my connectionstring from Web.config to a separate file, which I do not include in my public git repository. How can I generate this file for appveyor to use, without having to publically share my database password?

I understand there is the "secure" variable, but how could I use this while generating my apps connectionstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need this transformation for deployment with WebDeploy. In this case you can use [parametrization](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy/#web-deploy-parametrization). Also please read this [support forum discussion](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/1759-webconfig-using-web-deploy)  and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428870/msdeploy-setparameter-not-working).

If your scenario is different, please elaborate.

Comment: That is not the case, sadly. The project itself (without WebDeploy) always depends on the MSSQL server and therefore also the connectionstring within connections.config. Without it, the build fails entirely. https://ci.appveyor.com/project/amivit/crawler2/build/6
So I need a safe way to include connections.config before build time, within the debug/release folder

Comment: In this case maybe you can simple edit web.config with PowerShell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646769/editing-xml-with-powershell) and use secure variables (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables) to pass connection string to PowerShell?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable suggestion, I will try it out. Thanks!