# How to update node type element in xml file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a sample below xml file. I would like to update element settings node and change it "NewSettings" (highlighted in bold). I tried doing it through powershell using different properties and methods to change it, however it is not working out.

```
<configuration>
  **<Settings>**
    <test.Settings>
Some text block
    </test.Settings>
  **</Settings>**
</configuration>
```

I have tried below so far and some other powershell method to change element but it is not working

```
$path             = 'C:\temp1\web6.config'

$Newsetting        = 'NewSettings'

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)

$newxml = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Settings")

$newxml.InnerText = $Newsetting

$xml.Save($path)
```

Comment: If I run your code it appears to replace the entire *inner* contents of your ```<Settings>…</Settings/>``` with the text in ```$newsetting``` which is what I’d expect it to do (try adding the line ```write-host $xml.OuterXml``` at the end of your script to see the result). Can you show what *your* expected result is? (I note you’re not saving the updated xml back to the original in your sample, btw - is *that* the problem?)

Comment: thanks for responding and yes you are right, it changes the entire content of <Settings>…</Settings/> and I am thinking because I am using innertext method.

I am saving the file at the last. code edited.

Comment: Can you also show what your *expected* result is?

Comment: Do you want to just rename the `Settings` element to `NewSettings`? This is not directly possible (the `Name` property is immutable). So you basically have to create a new element with the desired name, copy any attributes and children from the old element to the new element and then delete the old element.

Answer (score 0):

See: [How can I update the value for a XML node using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202567/how-can-i-update-the-value-for-a-xml-node-using-powershell)

The `InnerText` property changes the text within an element, not the element’s name. You need to create a new element with the desired name, clone the attributes and children from the old element to the new one, replace, and save.

This script will replace the `<Settings>` element with a `<NewSettings>` element, keeping all attributes and child elements.

```
$path = 'C:\temp1\web6.config'
$Newsetting = 'NewSettings'

# Load the XML file
$xml = xml

# Select the node to be renamed
$oldNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Settings")

# Create a new node with the new name
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement($Newsetting)

# Clone attributes and children from the old node to the new node
foreach ($attribute in $oldNode.Attributes) {
    $newAttribute = $xml.CreateAttribute($attribute.Name)
    $newAttribute.Value = $attribute.Value
    $newNode.Attributes.Append($newAttribute)
}
foreach ($childNode in $oldNode.ChildNodes) {
    $newNode.AppendChild($childNode.Clone())
}

# Replace the old node with the new node in the parent
$oldNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($newNode, $oldNode)

# Save the XML document
$xml.Save($path)
```

Try this and let me know if this helps.